# Getting a distinct code-name pair but sorting on other columns

Tags: sql

I'm a bit stumped on writing a query (SQL not my strong point).

Say I have the following `TABLE1`:

```
CODE NAME     SCOPE1  SCOPE2    SEQ
------------------------------------
A    a        Here              1
B    b        Here              2
C    c        Here              3
C    c                Room      1
A    aa               Room      2
B    bbb              Room      3
```

The business key is `CODE + SCOPE1 + SCOPE2`, where `SCOPE1` and `SCOPE2` are always mutually exclusive.

How can I get a distinct result of `CODE` and `NAME` given that I need sort by `SCOPE1`, `SCOPE2`, and `SEQ`?

That is, given `SCOPE1 = 'Here'` and `SCOPE2 = 'Room'`, I would like to get this result:

```
CODE NAME
---------
A    a
B    b
C    c
A    aa
B    bbb
```

Note: `C c` from `Room` is not wanted as it's a duplicate to `C c` from `Here`.

I do realise the limitation of using `DISTINCT` with `ORDER BY` and the best I could come up with was the following:

```
select distinct CODE, NAME from
(
    select CODE, NAME from MYTABLE
    where (SCOPE1='Here' or SCOPE2='Room')
    order by SCOPE1, SCOPE2, SEQ
);
```

The above produces the correct pairs but in the wrong sequence. I tried messing around with `GROUP BY`, but I guess I didn't know enough.

I have to stick with standard SQL (that is, no product-specific SQL constructs, unless it's Oracle, maybe), and I guess with this particular query, it's probably impossible to avoid subselects.

I would be very grateful for any pointers. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I've updated the data set, and based on peterm's answer, here's what I have so far: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee27b/1). The MIN/MAX trick doesn't work well when I start tweaking the sequences.

The assumption is that I will always search for one specific `SCOPE1` paired with one specific `SCOPE2`. But I need all `SCOPE1` records to appear before `SCOPE2`. The idea is that I don't care whether `CODE + NAME` comes from `SCOPE1` or `SCOPE2` - I just want unique pairs that are sorted by `SCOPE1`, `SCOPE2`, and `SEQ`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE** Based on your updated requirements for Oracle

```
SELECT CODE, NAME
  FROM
(
  SELECT CODE, NAME, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SCOPE1, SCOPE2, SEQ) rnum
    FROM Table1
   WHERE SCOPE1='Here' 
      OR SCOPE2='Room'
) q 
 GROUP BY CODE, NAME
 ORDER BY MIN(rnum)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee27b/16)**

To make it work the same way in SQL Server

```
SELECT CODE, NAME
  FROM
(
  SELECT CODE, NAME, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN SCOPE1 IS NULL 
                                          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, SCOPE1,
                                     CASE WHEN SCOPE2 IS NULL 
                                          THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, SCOPE2, SEQ) rnum
    FROM Table1
   WHERE SCOPE1='Here' 
      OR SCOPE2='Room'
) q 
 GROUP BY CODE, NAME
 ORDER BY MIN(rnum)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/deb00/18)**

Output:

```
| CODE | NAME |
---------------
|    A |    a |
|    B |    b |
|    C |    c |
|    A |   aa |
|    B |  bbb |
```

**Original answer:** The only thing I could think of based on your description of requirements

```
SELECT CODE, NAME
  FROM Table1
 WHERE SCOPE1='Here' 
    OR SCOPE2='Room'
 GROUP BY CODE, NAME
 ORDER BY MIN(SCOPE1), MIN(SCOPE2), MIN(SEQ)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54c6e/2)** demo (MySql)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c41440/4)** demo (SQL Server)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/331a0/1)** demo (Oracle)

Now in MySql and SQL Server `NULL`s go first by default therefore you'll get

```
| CODE | NAME |
---------------
|    B |  bbb |
|    A |    a |
|    B |    b |
|    C |    c |
```

In Oracle `NULL`s go last by default therefore you'll get

```
| CODE | NAME |
---------------
|    A |    a |
|    B |    b |
|    C |    c |
|    B |  bbb |
```

Comment: Came up with something similar (except for the order by min scopes). Here's what you have in a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41d19/18)

Comment: @spullen unfortunately using `DESC` will produce wrong results if we add more rows with different values for scope1 and scope2

Comment: Wow, thanks for SQLFiddle link. Didn't know about that site at all. The query's alllmost there though. If I were to add a `C c` for 'Room' [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab5d1/1/0), I'm not too sure why 'C' gets sorted before 'B'.

Comment: I suspect that it's caused by the GROUP BY, something deciding to placing the `C c` ahead of the two `B` despite the order by... I think I'll go back to trying it with a subselect.

Comment: @aberrant80 Please see updated answer for a solution. I hope this will help.